# Ruby on rails 3 - If then add +1 to a variable that is later on printed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, variables, if-statement

Hi
I want to make a variable and add +1 if a statement is true, and then after I have looped through all statements show the total of that variable.

```
<% @variable_with_counts = 0 %>
<% games.each do |game|%>
  <% if game_is_true?(game.id) %>
    <% @variable_with_counts += 1 %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= @variable_with_counts %>
```

This gives me no total, but only 0 or 1.

I'm novice as you can see...

**UPDATE**
Weird, now that I tested it again, it worked, sorry!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems you put too much logic in your view though.

Comment: agree with apnea - you might want to consider moving this instance variable into a controller for a better MVC approach

Comment: @Will, IMO it would be even better to make it as a class method in the Game model, instead of doing this in the controller. This would allow something like `games.number_of_trues`.

Comment: @mischa very true - just offered the simple solution as a quick fix but if the OP can work a method into the model that would be ideal

Comment: Yeah, I totally agree, I will apply the solution below and reduce the code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a more oop-like and functional approach to your problem which will in turn reduce logic within the view. How about this?

```
<%= games.all.count {|game| game_is_true? game.id } %>
```

To make it even shorter, make "game_is_true?" a method of your game class:

```
class Game << ActiveRecord::Base

  def is_true?
    game_is_true? self.id # or whatever evaluates this
  end

end
```

So it comes out as:

```
<%= games.all.count {|game| game.is_true? } %>
```

Depending on your ActiveRecord version, you may need to replace "all" with "each" or "to_a". If "game_is_true?" is actually evaluating SQL fields it would make more sense to turn it into a scope method with a where clause, so you could do "games.is_true.count" which reduces SQL overhead.